# way to link the internal active directory to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app, integration, appexchange

Researching for a way to link our internal Outlook database (Personal information like a number, position, and other information).

This is regarding people who either work in or with our organization, not clients.

In this case, I am not referring to Salesforce for Outlook. The system we are looking for would ideally be able to update and/or add contacts to our Salesforce database without having to export and import them manually.